# Turn off product url in magento cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to disable URL's in the cart in magento.

looking in the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

I see the cart items are checked if they have a product url

```
    <h2 class="product-name">                                                
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>                                     
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>                                                           
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>             
    <?php endif; ?>                                                          
    </h2>
```

If so, the URL's are rendered and if not, just the product name (this is what I want).

**now, easy fix - I can modify this template and just spit out the name (in my own package/theme of course) and my problem is solved.**

But I got curious and wondered what `$this->hasProductUrl()` looked like.

So, after some digging, I see in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml`

in the `checkout_cart_index` block, there lies the layout for this page.

specifically the block which `$this` refers to: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    ...
    <reference name="content">                                               
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">                    
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>                                
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            ...
</checkout_cart_index>
```

so when I checkout the method, `hasProductUrl` on this block object I notice right away, it will return false if the product urls are set to be ignored?!

```
/**                                                                          
 * Check Product has URL                                                     
 *                                                                           
 * @return bool                                                              
 */                                                                          
public function hasProductUrl()                                              
{                                                                            
    if ($this->_ignoreProductUrl) {                                          
        return false;                                                        
    }   
    ...
}
```

There is also, a nice little public method to switch this variable in the same block object

```
/**                                                                          
 * Set ignore product URL rendering                                          
 *                                                                           
 * @param bool $ignore                                                       
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer                            
 */                                                                          
public function setIgnoreProductUrl($ignore = true)                          
{                                                                            
    $this->_ignoreProductUrl = $ignore;                                      
    return $this;                                                            
}
```

But I cannot see where / how I could use this?

I don't know how I can call this method from the layout file, b/c these renderer blocks are already included from within a layout  call.

Anyone know if there is a proper way to call this function?

Answer (score 2):

You can call block method through the XML and can change **_ignoreProductUrl** flag to TRUE/FALSE.

Here is an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple">
            <action method="setIgnoreProductUrl">
                <argument name="ignore" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```